# How can I mimic inertial scrolling in a custom UIView when I can't use UIScrollView?

Tags: ipad, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I need to implement an "infinite scrolling" timeline, where the pinch-to-zoom will change the scale of the timeline rather than zoom on the underlying view, almost exactly like the scroll view of the app iStreamer (see below). I don't think I can do this with UIScrollView and am considering implementing a custom UIView that draws the timeline and its contents.

Are there any classes/formulas/constants that can provide the physics simulation behind the "glass on liquid" effect of inertial scrolling?

[image: iStreamer UI]

iStreamer (above) has overlapping touchable elements and inertial scrolling. They might be doing this with a regular UIScrollView, but I don't know how to achieve the same effect. I need to add elements that could span very wide stretches (years or decades on a timeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a UIScrollView, and don't allow zooming on the scrollview. Instead, add a pinch gesture recognizer which implements the desired behaviour for the pinch behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIGestureRecognizer as jer suggested, otherwise this might help: http://macresearch.org/dynamics-scrolling